# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin{(x^2-1)}}{x-1}$

Tags: limits, functions

My problem is to calculate

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin{(x^2-1)}}{x-1}$$

I evaluated to $\frac{\sin(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}$ and then to $\sin(x+1)$ but I wonder about the result of limit as x approach 1 of $\sin{(x+1)}$. I cannot think of any result I cannot connect to anything.

Comment: shouldn't that be x^2-1?

Comment: wait a sec... $\sin(x^2-1) \ne \sin(x+1)\cdot (x-1)$!!! You need to make sure you know what $\sin$ is before doing any calculations with it. According to your reasoning $\frac{\sin x}{x} ``=" \sin$

Comment: maybe you can help me user88595?

Comment: OP, you need to make clear which terms are inside the sine function, and which (if any) are outside.  Also, as @Awesome points out, you need $x^2-1$ instead.

Comment: @random : My point is you can't cancel them out just by a division. Think of it at $f(x)/x$ where $f(x) = \sin x$. You can't say $f(x)/x ``="f$ can you? Same goes with $\sin$, it's a function. I want to make sure you understand this before helping you out with an answer. Also as other said, I think you mean $x^2 - 1$, please correct if that's so.

Comment: yes my mistake,its sin(x^2 -1)

Answer (score 7):

Notice

$$ \frac{\sin ( x^2 - 1 )}{x-1} = \frac{\sin ( x^2 - 1 )}{x-1} \cdot \frac{ x+1}{x+1} = \frac{\sin ( x^2 - 1 )}{x^2-1} \cdot (x+1) \to_{x \to 1} 2 $$

since

$$ \frac{ \sin y}{y} \to_{y \to 0} 1 $$

Answer (score 3):

As we can see in the comments, this problem has only real meaning, if really which is to be calculated, is

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin{(x^2-1)}}{x-1}.$$

In this case, you can use the rule of l'Hospital (deriving both side):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\cos{(x^2-1)*2x}}{1}$$.

And from this you can simply substitute 1:

$$\frac{\cos{(1^2-1)}*2*1}{1}=\underline{\underline{2}}$$

Comment: since when is the derivative of $x-1$ equal to $-1$?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh, sorry! You have right, I fixed.

Comment: also, I don't know what "this problem has only real meaning, if really which is to be calculated" means. the mistaken problem, with $x^2+1$ instead of $x^2-1$, "has" just as much "meaning" as the problem with $x^2-1$. just because a limit doesn't exist doesn't mean the problem lacks "meaning."

Answer (score 2):

The limit $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sin(x^2+1)}{x-1}$$ obviously doesn't exist; the numerator tends to $\sin 2>0$, but the denominator tends to $0$. As you approach from the right, you're blowing up to $+\infty$, and as you approach from the left, you're blowing up to $-\infty$.

If you meant $\sin(x^2-1)$, just use L'Hopital's rule.